# stopping proguard damaging annotations in android library project

Tags: android, annotations, proguard

I am using GREE sdk for social stuff in my game. While exporting signed apk, proguard messes up some custom annotations in GREE sdk. (I am using GREE sdk as a library project in my game)

If I add nothing to proguard config. It obfuscate GREE SDK as well and it throws me "Inject (Custom annotation in gree sdk)" missing annotation exception, when I try to install and run game.

First I added this keep statement to skip obfuscation of whole GREE SDK.

```
-keep class net.gree.** {
  public protected private *;
}
```

This helped me avoiding sdk code from being obfuscate but 'Annotations' were still removed and I am still receiving same exception.

then I tried adding this `-keepattributes` statements one by one but non of them helped me.

```
a) -keepattributes *Annotation*
b) -keepattributes Inject
c) -keepattributes net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Inject
d) -keepattributes @net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Inject
```

(d) option throws cannot  find file `/CLASSPATH OF PRJECT/net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Inject`

Here is my proguard config file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-dontwarn org.mockito.cglib.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class net.gree.** {
  public protected private *;
}
```

Exception that I am trying to get rid of:

```
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.mygame.Application: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a suitable constructor in net.gree.asdk.core.track.TrackItemStorageImpl. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4154)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a suitable constructor in net.gree.asdk.core.track.TrackItemStorageImpl. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Binder.getConstructorOf(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Binder.createInstance(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Binder.getOrCreateInstance(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Binder.createInstance(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Binder.finishBinding(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.inject.InternalInjector.createInjector(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.Injector.init(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.core.Core.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at net.gree.asdk.api.GreePlatform.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at com.aqif.speedymind.application.SpeedyApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
11-06 12:25:41.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10764):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
################### GREE SDK ##################
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Inject <fields>;
    @net.gree.asdk.core.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}


##################### GSON #####################
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

 # Model classes parsed by GSON
-keep class net.gree.asdk.** {
    public protected private *;
}
```

It is similar to another response but using GREE specific annotation.

Answer (score 5):

You should add some configuration in your proguard file to keep annotated classes (both constructors and fields) using the Inject annotation :

```
 # keeps all fields and Constructors with @Inject
 -keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <fields>;
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
 }
```

Comment: Thnxs this was more accurate way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this
    -keep class net.gree.** {
      public protected private *;
    }

I had to do this

```
-keep class net.gree.** {
   *;
}
```